# Inserting Php Files

Tags: php, html, include

I'm learning PHP and right now i'm learning how to add files.

However,

I'm having trouble importing for example, my header.php into my index.php file.

My browser is stuck loading, and nothing is displayed.

I have two php files; a footer.php and a header.php that i'm trying to include into a index.php

Here's my code for 
Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page['title'];?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerr">
<?php
  $page = array();
  include 'footer.php';
?>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>
        Hola
    </h1>
    <article>
        Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.
    </article>
</div>
<div class="footterr">
<?php
 include 'footer.php';
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php echo '
<!-- top menu bar -->
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Home</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Site Map</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Search</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Help</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- header ends -->
' ?>
```

footer.php

```
<?php echo'
<!-- footer begins -->
<br />
<center>Your usage of this site is subject to its published <a href="tac.html">terms and conditions</a>. Data is copyright Big Company Inc, 1995-<?php echo date("Y", mktime()); ?></center>

'
?>
```

Comment: So the php you want to be echoed is not displaying or your entire page is now blank?

Comment: Both header and footer are missing the semicolon after the `echo`. FWIW you appear to be importing the footer into the top _and_ bottom of your page.

Comment: it seems you are including `footer.php` in both the includes instead of `header.php` in top

Comment: @MikeW I'm not sure the semi-colon is required. I often use `<?= $foo ?>` without a semi-colon

Comment: @Phil Try it on codepad,org with `echo` - fails every time.

Comment: @MikeW Just tried it locally. You must be doing something else on codepad because it works fine for me ~ http://codepad.org/UapisczT

Comment: @av17, when you say "nothing is displayed" do you mean nothing at all or no output is seen for the php portions of the code block?

Comment: How are you accessing these files, on your own computer or via the Web? If from your computer: Is PHP installed, or are you trying to view these files straight from the browser as if they were browser-parsed HTML files? Other than trying to figure out how you're wanting to use `<?php echo $page['title'];?>` everything checks out here.

Comment: When I say "nothing is displayed" I mean, 

I'm using PHPStorm with WAMP, I open it with the chrome browser and a tab opens up, nothing loads on the page ( blank window ) and there is a loading animation in the tab.  I've just firefox aswell and it's the same thing.. I don't have any errors showing

Comment: **BINGO** - There you go. You can't access those files that way. PHP needs to be installed and properly configured (*if it's not installed, which I tend to think it's not*), otherwise they won't be parsed properly. PHPStorm is an editor, not a parser/browser.

Comment: This is the only time i've had this problem, I've ran php files before, but it's only with this i've had problems.

Comment: Define "only time". This clearly tells me that PHP is not installed. As I said, your code checks out. There's nothing more I can do here. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot semi colon on your header and footer. and also you dont need to re open the php in footer for time function (you only need to append it to the text)

header:

```
<?php echo '
<!-- top menu bar -->
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Home</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Site Map</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Search</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Help</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- header ends -->
'; ?>
```

footer:

```
    <?php echo'
    <!-- footer begins -->
    <br />
    <center>Your usage of this site is subject to its published <a href="tac.html">terms and conditions</a>. Data is copyright Big Company Inc,  1995-' . date("Y", mktime()) . '
</center>
     ';
        ?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure they're required in this context. The `?>` delimiter is usually enough to signify end-of-statement

Comment: Awesome thanks eddie, but it's still not loading.
I'm using PHPstorm and i go to chrome, it opens in the browser, but nothing is displayed on the page and there is the loading animation in the tab.

Comment: @av17, when you remove the include 'footer.php' and 'header.php' from your index, does your page load?

Comment: Thanks Eddie (: You fixed it.

Thanks for being my first upvote

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use **echo** on **footer.php** and **header.php**. Your **index.php** looks fine to me.

**footer.php**

```
<!-- footer begins -->
<br />
<center>Your usage of this site is subject to its published <a href="tac.html">terms and conditions</a>. Data is copyright Big Company Inc, 1995-<?php echo date("Y", mktime()); ?></center>
```

**header.php**

```
<!-- top menu bar -->
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Home</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Site Map</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Search</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Help</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- header ends -->
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a comment instead?